# Leverage Round Robin DNS for image transfer

Tags: dns, distributed-computing

I have images that are replicated to several different machines. But it takes a while to replicate these images and sometimes a request is made for one that isn't there. Can I use DNS Round Robin by telling the client (browser) to use a different IP address if the image isn't found? If so, how would I do this? Can I just return an HTTP code or do I have to have the client request timeout?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use DNS for that. You have no control over when, how and to where the user's browser sends DNS queries.